# jquery cookie set css to display: none

Tags: jquery, css, dom, cookies

I'm using the jquery cookie plugin and I'm trying to have the browser remember the state of a CSS after a refresh, here's my code when a button is clicked:

```
    $('#cartHolder').attr('style','display: none !important');
    $.cookie("cartDisplay", 'none !important');
```

Then in my header I have:

```
   if ($.cookie("cartDisplay")){
       $('#cartHolder').attr('style', $.cookie("cartDisplay"));
   }
```

The problem is, after each refresh the `display`property is still reset back to it's default property. However in the console window I see that jquery cookie has successfully stored the necessary value, it's just not being written into the DOM after each refresh.

Any one able to help me out?

Thanks

Comment: Your cookie value only contains `none !important`, you need to add `display:`

Comment: Please use JS FIDDLE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should not use `attr('style')` as it will **override** all your styles. Use `.css` instead. An also try avoiding `!important`. Try

```
$('#cartHolder').css('display','none');
$.cookie("cartDisplay", 'none');
```

In your header.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($.cookie("cartDisplay")){
           $('#cartHolder').css('display', $.cookie("cartDisplay"));
       }
});
```

Or you could use `.toggle`

```
$('#cartHolder').hide();
$.cookie("cartDisplay", 'false');
```

In your header.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($.cookie("cartDisplay")){
           $('#cartHolder').toggle($.cookie("cartDisplay"));
       }
});
```

Remember to wrap the code inside `$(document).ready(function(){` to ensure the DOM elements **have been loaded**

Comment: correct but its duplicate I think and could be a comment under an answer.

Comment: OK nice +1 to your description. please check mine too.

Comment: @KhanhTO yep that's it, sorry for this elementary mistake. Forgot to include document.ready  :D  cheers

Answer (score 3):

The String You get back from your cookie is this:

```
none !important
```

and the thing you give to your element is this:

```
 <div style="none !important"></div>
```

make it complete in your coockie, like:

```
display:none !important
```

**EDIT**
its better to use it like this:

```
 $('#cartHolder').css('display', $.cookie("cartDisplay"))
```

and there is no need to change the cookie code of yours.(it should work)

Comment: I've tried your suggestion and it still returns undefined in the final CSS in the DOM

Comment: sorry i didnot get it do you need description? and plus thanks for your +1